# Getting child element in XAML by type

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have xaml button like so:

```
      <Button Click="SyncToDeviceToggle_OnClick">
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="Img/kin.png" Height="25"/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>
```

Code behind:

```
private void SyncToDeviceToggle_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var image = ??//I want to get the child image element in the button without having to search for it by name specified in name="something"
}
```

In javascript i would just do
     button.getElementsByTagName("image")[0];

Comment: By setting the image, are you just trying to change the background of the button?? Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Don't work on control template use ContentTemplate. As it will keep your button working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        Button button = sender as Button;
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(button, 0);
        Image image = child as Image;
        //Now you can access your image Properties
}
```

Comment: And now, how to get the `Image` control from the Button's `Template`? That was the question.

Comment: @Clemens it was a relevant answer anyway, you cant downvote each and every answer

Comment: Your first post did not provide an answer to the question. You're answering fast and you nearly always miss the point. It is still hard to tell in your current answer why there is a `FrameworkElement fe` instead of an `Image`.

Comment: @Clemens ya, got it :)

Answer (score 1):

You could assign a name to the Image control and then access it by means of the [`FindName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname.aspx) method of the Button's `Template`:

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <Image x:Name="image" Source="Img/kin.png" Height="25"/>
</ControlTemplate>
```

...

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = (Control)sender;
    var image = control.Template.FindName("image", control) as Image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Button Click="SyncToDeviceToggle_OnClick" Margin="0,224,0,302">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Img/kin.png" x:Name="MyBrush"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
```

If done in this way, you can directly access MyBrush by its direct name in the .cs file.