# Accessing a xaml.cs file from another xaml.cs file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

is it possible to cast to another xaml.cs file without creating a new object of that class.

For example, you can use this to access MainWindow variables/methods.

```
MainWindow window = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
```

My question: is it possible to do something like the above but for another page that is not main window. example:

```
MyPage window = (MyPage )Application.Current.MyPage;
```

reason for needing is say if a frame.source has a loaded xaml page, i want to access that pages functions to get current info on that page. if you create a new object of that page then i can not get the data i want.

Comment: You might want to check Loaded event inside your xaml page and cast Object sender to your page. Similar question with solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23647993/getting-child-element-in-xaml-by-type)

Comment: Do you mean something like the `System.Linq` `OfType<>` extension? e.g.`Application.Current.Windows.OfType<YourWindowBaseClass>()`

Comment: Note that at any monent, there might be 0, 1, or any number of instances of MyPage.

Comment: i want the first instance of the page object when the source is binded to the frame.and yeah i think thats what i mean @StefanWuebbe

Comment: yeah :), then I could post a snippet if you want. It would be about the `Window` class again though but easy to modify and contain Linq `SingleOrDefault()` vs `FirstOrDefault()` aspects for the "0, 1, any" trap that @KlausGütter mentioned

Comment: @Getwrong: Is `MyPage` an currently opened window or what is it?

Comment: I think the best practice for communicate between two object without instance reference, is Messaging system